# V13 Discord.JS Bot is not sending messages

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

This's my code below, I have tried enabling Intents from the developer portal, and I've checked the channel permissions, and my node version is running on v16.14.2, and still, it doesn't send any messages for some reason.

```js
const { Client, Intents } = require("discord.js");
const { token } = require("./config.json");

const client = new Client({
    intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS, Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGE_REACTIONS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES],
});
client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("Ready");
});

client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
    if (message === "ping") {
        message.reply({
            content: "pong",
        });
    }
});

client.login(token);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing an object with a string, the error is in your if() statement:

```
if(message.content=='ping'){
    message.reply('pong')
}
```

Comment: Damn I didn't realize that it's my first time using discordjs

Comment: Don't worry! You can check https://discordjs.guide/#before-you-begin